# Datepicker and timepicker from within a single Dialog

Tags: android-widget

Please tell me how to implement both Datepicker and timepicker from within a single Dialog.

Thanks,
susanta

Answer (score 1):

Might be worth taking a look at this

http://code.google.com/p/datetimepicker/